# jQuery on click not working on ajaxified elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's JS code:

```
    $('body').on('click', '.thumb', function() {
        alert(123);
    });
```

When you click on div with class `.thumb` it should alert the message, however, when i click - nothing happening.

Comment: where did you place the script? is it in the header

Comment: which file contains the script

Comment: Script is in the <head> section and it's called vasya.js

Comment: is there any code that is preventing event propagation?

Comment: When you click on a .thumb it executing ajax command. I suspect that

Comment: looks like somebody is stopping the event propagation from the a.ajax-processed element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.mousedown()` instead of .on('click'):

```
$('.thumb').mousedown(function() {
    alert(123);
});
```

With `.mousedown()` your JS code will fire only after Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/d83p7/

```
$('.thumb').click(function(e){

 e.preventDefault(); 
alert("Horaa");

});
```

Or

```
$('body .thumb').click(function(e){

 e.preventDefault(); 
alert("Horaa");

});
```

OR

```
$('.thumb').live('click',function(e){

 e.preventDefault(); 
alert("Horaa");

});
```

OR

```
$('.thumb').bind('click',function(e){

 e.preventDefault(); 
alert("Horaa");

});
```

or

```
$('body').on('click', '.thumb', function(e) {

 e.preventDefault(); 
alert("Horaa");

});
```

place the examples inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //code here
});
```

Comment: did you have javascript error on your browser console ?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out :

```
$('body').delegate('.thumb', 'click', function(e){
   alert('123');
});
```